# Performing circular shif on values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have to construct a large dictionary which looks something like this

```
{'A' : {'A' : 1, 'B' : 0, 'C' : 0}, 
'B' : {'A' : 0, 'B' : 1, 'C' : 0}} 
............................
```

Each inner dictionary is shifted by one position. Is there a way I can automate this process.

I can loop and use `np.roll()` function if it were `ndarray` so I am wondering if there's something similiar I could do with dictionaries.

Comment: Maybe use a deque instead

Comment: On python, dictionaries are implemented as hash tables and are unordered. So, your "positions" are meaningless. Did you mean collections.OrderedDict?

Comment: @utdemir not meaningless here.  he is rotating the values with respect to the keys.

Comment: So, are we assuming keys are in natural alphabetical order?

Comment: No I just made up an example to illustrate my problem. Keys are strings

Comment: It might be efficient to store keys and inner dicts in separate lists. This makes shifting rather easy, but indexing by key gets cumbersome.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate) for fast dictionary values (list) shifting (deque `rotate` function) but there is no specific function for dictionary, you should make it yourself, for example:

```
# shift dct (dict) values by n to right if n is positive
# and to left if n is negative; returns new dictionary
def dict_roll(dct, n):
    shift_values = deque(dct.values())
    shift_values.rotate(n)
    return dict(zip(dct.keys(), shift_values))
```

Demo:

```
>>> d = {'A': {'A': 1, 'C': 0, 'B': 0}, 'B': {'A': 0, 'C': 0, 'B': 1}}
>>> for k in d:
...     d[k] = dict_roll(d[k], 1)
... 
>>> d
{'A': {'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'B': 0}, 'B': {'A': 1, 'C': 0, 'B': 0}}
>>> for k in d:
...     d[k] = dict_roll(d[k], 1)
... 
>>> d
{'A': {'A': 0, 'C': 0, 'B': 1}, 'B': {'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'B': 0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create your string in `r`:

```
import string
r = {}
a = [1] + [0] * 25
for i in string.ascii_uppercase:
     r[i] = dict(zip(string.ascii_uppercase,a))
     a = a[-1:] + a[:-1]
print r
```

#### Bonus one-liner

If you are using Python 2.7+ or Python 3, then you can get a one-liner using dictionary comprehensions:

```
import string
{i:{j:1 if i==j else 0 for j in string.ascii_uppercase} for i in string.ascii_uppercase}
```

Answer (score 0):

And another solution.

Solution 1:

```
out = dict()
syms = ['A', 'B', 'C']

for sym_outer in syms:
    inner_dict = dict()
    for sym_inner in syms:
        inner_dict[sym_inner] = 0 if sym_inner != sym_outer else 1
    out[sym_outer] = inner_dict
```

Solution 2:

This is a partial solution, but you get out['A']['A'] == 1 and out['A']['B'] == 0.

```
from collections import defaultdict

out = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for sym in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
    out[sym][sym] = 1
```